# Can pressure drops in a heat exchanger shell side be super low?

Tags: heat-transfer, chemical-engineering, heat-exchanger

i'm a chemical eng. student from Italy and i'm "sizing" ("setting"?) a heat exchanger to cool some octane with toluene.

Is it possible that pressure drops shell side in a 1,2 pull-through floating head heat exchanger are lower than 0.001 atmosphere? I used really wide buffles and buffle cuts opened at 45%. The heat exchange is in range and the pressure drops tube side are "normal" (0.2 atm). I just find it weird that shell side they are so low. Can someone help me?

Comment: "I" is always UPPERCASE in English.

Comment: You should have written EnglIsh, then. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a vague question but I can give you two pieces of information which may help:

1. In theory the pressure drop can be arbitrarily low. That is to say that if the flowrate is small enough relative to the size of the flow path, then the pressure drop could be 0.001 atm.
2. In practice, for any heat exchanger design you would not have a pressure drop that low. If your pressure drop is that low I suggest the heat exchanger is over-sized and uneconomical to produce.